# Redirect file is not working PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have a very specific question. My problem is that I want people to be redirected to a specific website but for that there is a redirect.php file. In order to be redirected I need to send information using POST method from my html . The problem is that it does redirect me to my homepage... here's a simplified code of mine:

```
<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        ?>
        <form action="" method="POST"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-pressed="true" name="bank1"><img src="img/cart.png"><b> Pay by bank</b></button></form></div>  
        <form action="" method="POST"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-pressed="true" name="bank2"><img src="img/cart.png"><b> Pay by bank</b></button></form></div>
        <form action="" method="POST"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-pressed="true" name="bank3"><img src="img/cart.png"><b> Pay by bank</b></button></form></div>
        <form action="" method="POST"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-pressed="true" name="bank4"><img src="img/cart.png"><b> Pay by bank</b></button></form></div>
        <?php
    }
    else if ($_POST['bank1']) {
        require_once 'libwebtopay/redirect.php';
    }
    else {
        ?>
        <form action="" method="POST"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-pressed="true" name="submit"><b>Login</b></button></form></div>
        <?php 
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

That else if is not working properly. It redirects me to the else { } stated page. Here's redirect.php simplified code:

```
 try { if (isset($_POST['bank1'])) {
$request = WebToPay::redirectToPayment(array(
    'projectid'     => $projectid,
    'sign_password' => $sign_pass,
    'orderid'       => $vardas,
    'amount'        => $vip1,
    'currency'      => 'EUR',
    'country'       => 'LT',
    'accepturl'     => $self_url.'/accept.php',
    'cancelurl'     => $self_url.'/cancel.php',
    'callbackurl'   => $self_url.'/callback.php',
    'test'          => 1,
)); }
```

Trying to include redirect.php file under each of the forms didn't help either. header('Location: libwebtopay/redirec.php'); won't help too. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Maybe you aren't clicking the right button? Only the button for `bank1` will enter the block with the `require_once`. Also we have no idea what `WebToPay::redirectToPayment` does.

Comment: I'm clicking the right button.. Here's the webtopay.php file and its functions https://bitbucket.org/paysera/libwebtopay/raw/default/WebToPay.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [value attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) to your submit buttons. Also, you can condense this to one form. You also had extraneous closing div tags, by the way.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-pressed="true" name="bank" value="1"><img src="img/cart.png"><b> Pay by bank</b></button> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-pressed="true" name="bank" value="2"><img src="img/cart.png"><b> Pay by bank</b></button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-pressed="true" name="bank" value="3"><img src="img/cart.png"><b> Pay by bank</b></button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-pressed="true" name="bank" value="4"><img src="img/cart.png"><b> Pay by bank</b></button>
</form>
```

You might need to add a check for which button was pressed (e.g. `if ($_POST['bank'] == '3') { ... }`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what should I do with those values? What's the difference between value and name?

Comment: When the user submits a form, their browser sends a variety of [name-value pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair). You can access the value that is assigned to a name in the the `$_POST` superglobal just like you did in your post: `$_POST['name']`. That would evaluate to the value. So if I click on a button that has the name `bank` and the value `"2"`, `$_POST['bank']` evaluates to `"2"`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it solved ^^ Ofc the problem wasn't here, it was the problem in $vardas variable because I got probably wrong and because of that it couldn't redirect correctly. Thank you!